# Multilevel dropdown menu won't go to the right

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have ran into a slight problem with my dropdown menu. I need and extra level in my dropdown, but i really don't know what to do with the CSS...

The page can be seen [here](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml).
The problem can be seen in the menu under "Om os", where "Brochure 2013", "Brochure 2014" should be visible when hovering over "Brochure" and not as it is now!

How to fix this?

Here's my CSS:

```
.cssmenu {
    border: 0px solid #2E181A;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: verdana,geneva,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2E181A;
    width: 798px;
    background: #E6D9BD;
    text-align: center;
}

.cssmenu ul {
    background: #E6D9BD;
    height: 37px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.cssmenu li {
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cssmenu li a {
    color: #2E181A;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 37px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cssmenu li a:hover {
    color: #8e8e8e;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cssmenu li ul {
    background: #E6D9BD;
    border-left: 5px solid #2E181A;
    border-right: 5px solid #2E181A;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2E181A;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.95;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 200;
    float: none;
        /*top:1em;
        /*left:0;*/;
}

.cssmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.cssmenu li li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 225px;
}

.cssmenu li ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.cssmenu li ul a:hover {
    background: #D5BE91;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
/* For IE8 and earlier */;
}

.cssmenu p {
    clear: left;
}

.cssmenu .active > a {
    background:;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.cssmenu .active > a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

And here's my menu:

```
<ul class="active">
    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/">Forside</a></span>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/hingste.shtml">Hingste</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/cash.shtml">Volstrups Cash</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/churchill.shtml">Churchill</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/cooper.shtml">Blejsbjergs Cooper</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/concosmos.shtml">Con Cosmos</a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/salgsheste.shtml">Salgsheste</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/charline.shtml">Volstrups Charline</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/calina.shtml">Volstrups Calina</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/colline.shtml">Volstrups Colline</a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/betingelser.shtml">Betingelser</a></span>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/omos.shtml">Om os</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/hestenu.shtml">Heste på stationen</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/samarbejde.shtml">Samarbejdspartnere</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/omos.shtml">Om Stutteriet</a></span>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/brochure.shtml">Brochure</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/brochure2014.shtml">Brochure for 2014</a></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span><a href="http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/brochure2013.shtml">Brochure for 2013</a></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Hope you guys can help me out! :)

Comment: Why do you have a `<span>` after every `<li>`?

Comment: Sure i can! [You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLvLG/), but it doesn't look like a menu at all....

Still easier to see [here](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml)

Comment: @Xareyo > I found it like this somewhere on the internet for a long time ago...

Comment: I just edited your answer with a beautified version of your HTML and CSS and I noticed your HTML is missing a closing `</ul>` tag for the top-level UL. If that's actually the case for your code, make sure to correct it and keep in mind proper indentation and structure will help you spot these mistakes.

Comment: Sry, just found out that i didn't copy/paste all the code... Some more was missing. But thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need woking with level3 ul.add some `margin-top` and`left to 100%`
just add this porperty to you css file:

```
.cssmenu li li:hover > ul{
    visibility:visible !important
}
    .cssmenu li ul ul {
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    border-left:none;
margin-left:-5px;

    }
.cssmenu li ul ul a{
border-left:5px solid #2E181A;
}
.cssmenu li ul ul li:first-child a{
border-left:none !important;

}
```

[image]

also you don't need add the `<a>` tag into `<span>`. you can remove that,

Comment: Thx, i've tried, but it come up all the time now and not only when hovering "Brochure". I have uploaded the new CSS, check the [page here](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml)

Comment: It won't let me edit my post... What tag do you mean that i don't need?

Comment: i edit my code,please replace that and check result; @SimonJensen

Comment: > YAY! It works! THX a lot!! :D Just as a little extra, is there a possibility that the border between this second level dropdown can be faded as it is between the menu and the first level?

Comment: your welcome,can you Specify you mean with image,maybe we can't @SimonJensen

Comment: > Sry for my limited english, but it can be seen [here in this pic](http://gupl.dk/707855/). Fade the border :)

Click the picture for a bigger pic

Comment: that's a little bit hard and you need change some code,i try to write that code,please replace my edited code and check result; @SimonJensen

Comment: > Again thx a lot! I did a little change in the margin sizes and now it really works! Thx a lot :D